# How to make a message disappear after a couple seconds elapse

Tags: reactjs

trying to make feedback from my backend disappear from the user's view after a form submits.  unsure of how to go about this.  the message is generated as follows in my handlesubmit:

```
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setIsLoading(true)
    const fireToken = await localStorage.FBIdToken
    await axios
      .post(`/user`, formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${fireToken}`
        }
      })

      .then(res => {
        setMessage(res.data)
        fetchProfile()
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setErrors(err.response.data)
        console.log(err)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
  }
```

I am setting the message in state and then using it in my return as follows:

```
           <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.customError}>
                  {message.message}
                </Typography>
```

unsure of what to do in order to set some sort of timeout any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: Try using the setTimeout function `setTimeout(Function, 3000)`
eg: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout like so

```
let _TIMER;
export function SomeComponent() {
...
  axios.post
  ...
  .then(res => {
    setMessage(res.data);
    fetchProfile();
    setIsLoading(false);
    clearTimeout(_TIMER);
    _TIMER = setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage();
      clearTimeout(_TIMER);
    }, 5000);
  });
  ....
  {message.message && <Typography variant ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't shared the whole code but I suppose that you can set a timeout in the `setMessage` method which updates the state after a few seconds:

```
setMessage(message)
{
    clearTimeout(this.messageClearTimeout);

    this.setState({message});

    this.messageClearTimeout = setTimeout(
        () => this.setState({message: null}),
        5000
    );
}
```

Comment: Im using hooks, so the setMessage is setting the res.data in state